# Submit multiple forms to same action page

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

Sorry if this one has been answered somewhere else but couldn't quite find the fool proof answer I need.

I have a update form page that contains a number of iframes, each iframe contains another form. I need to be able to hit submit on the parent page and as well as submitting the parents form fields but also the iframes form fields all to the same php script.

Looks like javascript is the way to go but I am a complete beginner with javascript so need some extremely dumbed down help and how to.

Comment: why use iframes? Why not include those other forms as A PART of the parent form but split them up into optional sections. Submit everything using one form and just pull out the values you need with php?

Comment: @bowlerae Because the php scripts, and drop down contents used in the page conflict with each other when used on the same page. The only way round it is to use 10 different external functions and when the lists require altering I would have to change all functions individually. Which to be honest I am a little too lazy to do.